# DPCT migration fails with error code (-5)

Tags: intel-oneapi, intel-dpct

I have updated my CUDA toolkit version to 11.4. When I try to migrate any CUDA code to DPC++ using DPCT tool, I get the following error:

*dpct exited with code: -5 (Error: Path for CUDA header files is invalid or not available. Specify with --cuda-include-path)*

I have even specified the cuda-include-path flag but the error still persists. I'm I missing something?

Environment:
OS: CentOS 8
oneAPI base tookit version: 2021.3

Answer (score 1):

DPCT tool does not support CentOS version 8. You can try using any of the supported versions of OS for DPCT migration.

Refer to the below link for the supported OS and their versions.

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-dpc-compatibility-tool-system-requirements.html